# Android Handler.postDelayed use in Recursion

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, android-handler, towers-of-hanoi

I am creating an app based on the Towers of Hanoi that includes an animation for each move, all less than one second long. I have one option where you can solve the puzzle manually and one where the program solves the puzzle itself, showing all of the animations. My issue occurs when the program tries to solve the puzzle itself. I've been trying to use `handler.postDelayed` within the recursive method that the puzzle uses to give each animation time to finish before attempting to start the next one:

```
int autoSolveCount = 0;

public void playHanoi(int n, String from , String other, String to) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    if (n == 0)
    {
        autoSolveCount++;
        return;
    }
    if (n > 0){
        playHanoi(n-1, from, to, other);
        image.get(from).performClick();
        image.get(to).performClick();
        handler.postDelayed(new RunAutoSolve(n-1, other, from, to), 1000*(autoSolveCount+1));
    }
}

public class RunAutoSolve implements Runnable{

    int num;
    String other = "";
    String from = "";
    String to = "";

    public RunAutoSolve(int n, String o, String f, String t){
        num = n;
        other = o;
        from = f;
        to = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        playHanoi(num, other, from, to);
    }
}
```

`image.get(to)` and `image.get(from)` return a clickable ImageView for the tower being targeted. When they are clicked, other methods run the proper animation. When I solve the puzzle manually, I run into no issues, so I doubt it's a problem with the clickable images or the animations. The problem seems to be that the program doesn't have enough time to finish executing the first animation before beginning the second. The way my methods are set up, it will crash if an animation tries to start before the other one is finished. (This is not an issue during a manual execution.) When I run the program, there is a long pause before the first animation, and it crashes right after that animation is complete. So, is this a problem with where I place the delay, the timing, or something else? If you need to see more of my code, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than a delay, if you want animations to run consecutively, you should use an animation completion listener to detect when each move has been made. You can then start a new animation for the next move.